# Pass json object from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a json array in php and I want to pass it to javascript so I can use it with google charts.

If I do this:

```
var a = <?php echo((json_encode($data))); ?>;
```

I get the data in the format `Name,Value,PHP,78,JAVA,1000,HTML,129` but I want to keep it in the `json` format that it was in

```
[["Name","Value"],["PHP",78],["JAVA",1000],["HTML",129]]​
```

because google charts needs to receive it like this.
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can't. Only workaround would be using AJAX or something.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$book = array(
    "title" => "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide",
    "author" => "David Flanagan",
    "edition" => 6
);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var book = <?php echo json_encode($book, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
/* var book = {
    "title": "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide",
    "author": "David Flanagan",
    "edition": 6
}; */
alert(book.title);
</script>
```

try it hope this will help...

Comment: no error just still getting it in the wrong format when I test. I think because I am changing it to a javascript variable but I just want to keep it as a json array

Comment: <?php
    $data = Array ();
 $data [] = Array ("Name", "Value");
 $data [] = Array ("PHP", 78);
 $data [] = Array ("JAVA", 1000);
 $data [] = Array ("HTML", 129);
    $table = json_encode($data);
 echo $table ; 
?>

Comment: sorry about how it looks, new to stackoverflow, don't really know how to use it